# Running yarn add requires sudo

Tags: yarnpkg

For some reason when I try to add packages to a project with `yarn add redux-thunk` it fails with

```
error An unexpected error occurred: 
"EACCES: permission denied, unlink '/Users/TuzMacbookPro2017/Development/code/ReactJS/recipe-helper-react-js/node_modules/.bin/acorn'".
```

or some other  `EACCES` error. Adding `sudo` works, but I shouldn't have to do that in this case, right?

I followed [these](https://docs.npmjs.com/resolving-eacces-permissions-errors-when-installing-packages-globally) steps (replacing `npm` with `yarn` and now `yarn add global` works without `sudo`.

How do I fix the permissions for the normal `yarn add` command?

Answer (score 4):

Most likely, at some point a package was added using `sudo` (in this case 'acorn').

Removing everything from node_modules and then reinstalling should fix it:

1. `sudo rm -rf /Users/TuzMacbookPro2017/Development/code/ReactJS/recipe-helper-react-js/node_modules/`
2. `yarn install`